# Magento 2 Perform catalog search in my custom table

Tags: magento2

Building a custom module where I need to search on the third-party table for data.

I have executed and filtered data from the third-party table and retrieve the entity_id from it and added the entity_id the below query.

```
$this->queryResponse = $this->searchEngine->search($queryRequest);
    $ids = [0];

    $productIds = $this->crossReferenceFactory->getProductIdsBySearch($this->queryText);

    if(count($productIds)>0){
        foreach($productIds as $id) 
            $ids[] = $id;   

    }
    /** @var \Magento\Framework\Search\Document $document */
    foreach ($this->queryResponse as $document) {
        $ids[] = $document->getId();
    }
    parent::addFieldToFilter('entity_id', ['in' => $ids]);
```

When I do such filter it lists the products perfectly fine, But when I query for words which exist only in the third-party table it doesn't build the layered navigation.

After debugging I come to know that layered navigation uses below method.

```
public function getFacetedData($field)
{
    $this->_renderFilters();
    $aggregations = $this->queryResponse->getAggregations();
    $bucket = $aggregations->getBucket($field . '_bucket');
    if (!$bucket) {
        throw new StateException(new Phrase('Bucket does not exist'));
    }
    $result = [];
    foreach ($bucket->getValues() as $value) {

        $metrics = $value->getMetrics();
        $result[$metrics['value']] = $metrics;
    }

    return $result;
}
```

So, When I search for any particular word it builds the layered navigation using `queryResponse` data.

My concern is how can I add my table to `$queryRequest` so that I can have a consistent result. Any help would highly appreciate.

Comment: Hi, Did you find solution for this? I am facing same issue. Please answer if you found please share here.

Comment: i am also facing same issue can any one share the answer?

Answer (score 1):

if you want to remove the dependency on Magento Fulltext catalog search then rewrite **`Magento/CatalogSearch/Model/Search/IndexBuilder.php`** file in your custom module and change SQL query(which will get data from your custom table) in function public function build **(RequestInterface $request)** then layer navigation filters also work properly.

Comment: please share the code

Answer (score 1):

The sample code for overriding **`Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Search\IndexBuilder`** is as follows:

> Namespace\Modulename\etc\di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Search\IndexBuilder">
        <plugin name="Namespace_Modulename::custom_collection" type="Namespace\Modulename\Plugin\CatalogSearch\Model\Search\IndexBuilder" />
    </type>
</config>
```

> Namespace\Modulename\Plugin\CatalogSearch\Model\Search\IndexBuilder.php

```
<?php
namespace Namespace\Modulename\Plugin\CatalogSearch\Model\Search;

use Magento\Framework\Search\RequestInterface;

class IndexBuilder {    
    protected $_request;
    protected $_categoryHelper;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory,
        \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Category $categoryHelper,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http $request
    ) {
        $this->_productCollectionFactory    = $productCollectionFactory;
        $this->_categoryHelper              = $categoryHelper;
        $this->_request                     = $request;
    }

    public function aroundBuild($subject, callable $proceed, RequestInterface $request) {
        $select = $proceed($request);

        $collection = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create();
        $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
        $collection->addAttributeToFilter('necessary_attribute', ['necessary_attribute' => 'attr_value']);
        $getProductAllIds = $collection->getAllIds();
        $productUniqueIds = array_unique($getProductAllIds);
        $select->where("search_index.entity_id IN ('" . join("','", $productUniqueIds) . "')");     
        return $select;
    }
}
```

Hope this may help you guys!!